# How to filter a ListView with custom adapter including two TextViews in Java

Tags: java, listview, filter, dialog, custom-adapter

I had a huge problem designing a custom arrayadapter, that can be filtered by writing text into an EditText. 
The regular way is to override the existing getFilter() with your custom getFilter() function.

I thought, I should share my solution to all of you (this one's shown in a dialog and can filter inside strings (and not as getFilter(), which is filtering the strings only by starting at the first character of each word)):

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.filter_list_custom_adapter;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    final ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> filterednames = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> filteredsubstring = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> substring = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_list);

                list = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listview);
                EditText theFilter = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.searchfilter);

                names.add("Bastian");
                names.add("Laura");
                names.add("Benjamin");
                names.add("Jonas");
                names.add("Deborah");
                names.add("Tabea");

                substring.add("male");
                substring.add("female");
                substring.add("male");
                substring.add("male");
                substring.add("female");
                substring.add("female");

                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.list_item,
                        names ) {
                    @Override
                    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
                        View rowView = convertView;
                        if (rowView == null) {
                            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,false);
                            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                            viewHolder.ftxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.filteredtextview);
                            viewHolder.ntxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.normaltextview);
                            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
                        } else {
                            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
                        }

                        viewHolder.ftxt.setText(names.get(position));
                        viewHolder.ntxt.setText(substring.get(position));

                        return rowView;
                    }
                };

                list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        filter(charSequence.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    }
                });


                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase();
        filterednames.clear();
        filteredsubstring.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            filterednames.addAll(names);
            filteredsubstring.addAll(substring);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
            {
                if (names.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(charText))
                {
                    filterednames.add(names.get(i));
                    filteredsubstring.add(substring.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.list_item,
                filterednames ) {
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                final ViewHolder viewHolder;
                View rowView = convertView;
                if (rowView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,false);
                    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                    viewHolder.ftxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.filteredtextview);
                    viewHolder.ntxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.normaltextview);
                    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
                } else {
                    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
                }

                viewHolder.ftxt.setText(filterednames.get(position));
                viewHolder.ntxt.setText(filteredsubstring.get(position));

                return rowView;
            }
        };

        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView ftxt;
        public TextView ntxt;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ftxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ntxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**dialog_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchFilter"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchFilter"
        android:id="@+id/listview"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Best regards,
DarkCat